# Fragment shader: "no matching overloaded function found" error

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

The problems come from the mandelbrot function:

```
vec3 mandelbrot (vec2 coord){
    vec2 z0 = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
    int number = fractal (z0, coord, 10000);    
    float v = float(number);
    float factor = 0.0;
    return paletize (v, factor);
}

int fractal (vec2 z0, vec2 c, int maxIterations){
 //doesn't matter
}

vec3 paletize (float v, float factor){
   doesn't matter
}
```

and here is the error message: https://gyazo.com/5516853ee2600b58a303fd609530fafe

fragment shader failed to compile: the error log is:

```
ERROR:0:13 ´fractal´:no matching overloaded function found
ERROR:0.13: '=' : cannot convert from const float to mediump int
ERROR:0:19: ´paletize´: no matching overloaded function found
ERROR:0:19: ´return´: function return is not matching type:
```

Comment: error message is there now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your fractal and paletize functions over mandelbrot.